# Throw an error if a dependent control is not present on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Ok, I'm making a couple of JQuery versions of the AJAXToolkit controls (we were having issues with the toolkit), and want to have a common version of the scripts they require on the page.

To do this, I was intending to have a JQueryControlManager control, and use it to insert scripts dynamically, preferably only scripts that are needed by controls on the page.

Does anyone know of an efficient way to:

- Check a ControlManager control exists on the page if some other JQueryControls do
- Add each control to a collection within the ControlManager, assuming the answer to the first point does not return the JQueryControlManager instance

OR

Does anyone have a suggestion for a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scripts specifically, ASP.NET already has a nice ScriptManager class that supports what you're trying to do. Call

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(key, url);
```

from your control with a unique key for each script and the framework will take care of avoiding duplicates. There are other similar methods on `ClientScriptManager` that may be useful.

If you still need to create an instance of your ControlManager you could either just enumerate over the `Page.Controls` collection looking for a control of that type, ie.

```
public ControlManager GetControlManager()
{
    foreach (Control control in Page.Controls)
    {
        if (control is ControlManager)
            return (ControlManager)control;
    }

    ControlManager manager = new ControlManager();
    Page.Controls.Add(manager);

    return manager;
}
```

*or* you could try storing the instance of ControlManager in the `Page.Items` dictionary.

*Warning:* I haven't tested this code, so treat it as pseudo-code.

Comment: Using Scriptmanager isn't really what I'm going for: I'm planning to do some clever stuff with which scripts are imported, and with the $(function() {}); As for iterating over the Page.Controls, this is horribly inefficient (also, Page.Controls needs to be iterated recursively), and a bit of a pain when you've got ~50 of the related controls on the page! Page.Items might work though...

Comment: Yeah, if performance is an issue then Page.Items would be better. I'm not sure that you'd have needed to iterate recursively, though - are you going to have multiple of these ControlManagers on one page at different levels in the control hierarchy?

Comment: Well, you need recursion unless it's on the very top level of the page, so if you're using a masterpage there can be issues. I'm going with Page.Items[typeof(ControlManager)], that's how the scriptmanager does it, so I guess it's the best option.